# Декомпиляция iOS-приложений

Tags: ios, appstore

Возможна ли декомпиляция приложений и с помощью каких инструментов, скаченных с AppStore?

Вопрос возник в связи с необходимостью опубликовать приложение.
На Андроиде я включал ProGuard, а для iOS как следует поступить?

Comment: да, все можно дезассемблировать и разобраться как оно работает.

> а для iOS как следует поступить

у Вас есть два варианта - либо публиковать, либо нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) декомпиляция возможна. [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334072/decompiling-objective-c-libraries) интересная дискуссия на эту тему.

2) На iOS нет надобности использовать какие-то сторонние инструменты для обфускации, поскольку код компилируется в машинный код (а не в байт-код как джава).